# Proving that lines $(-1+4t,3+t,1)$ and $(-13+12t,1+6t,2+3t)$ intersect

Tags: linear-algebra

> Prove that these lines intersect each other:
>   $$\begin{align}
> L_1 &= \{(x,y,z) = (-1\phantom{3}+\phantom{1}4t,3+t,1)\} \\
> L_2 &=\{(x,y,z) = (-13+12t,1+6t,2+3t)\}
> \end{align}$$

I thought that what I had to do was to solve

$$\begin{align}-1+4t&=-13+12t \\
3+t &=1+6t \\
1 &=2+3t
\end{align}$$

But I guess that is not the correct way to do it since it does not give me a consistency. How should I do it then?

Comment: You may need different variables for the two different lines. Try using $t$ for the parameter in $L_1$ and $s$ for the parameter in $L_2$.

Comment: Thanks, I guess it was a mistake of the instructions beacuse I though in doing that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to show that there exist $t$ and $t'$ such that $(−1+4t, 3+t, 1) = (−13+12t', 1+6t', 2+3t')$.

Answer (score 2):

A bit more geometrically, the direction vector for $L_1$ is $v_1=(4,1,0)$ and the direction vector for $L_2$ is $(12,6,3)$, or, rescaling, $v_2=(4,2,1)$. Let's find a vector orthogonal to both: This will be the normal vector to parallel planes containing the lines. Well, $n = v_1\times v_2 = (1,-4,4)$. The first line goes through the point $P_1=(-1,3,1)$ and the second line goes through the point $P_2=(-13,1,2)$. The planes with normal vector $n$ passing through these respective points are
$$x-4y+4z = (-1)-4(3)+4(1) = -9 \qquad\text{and}\qquad x-4y+4z=(-13)-4(1)+4(2)=-9.$$
Aha — the planes are identical. So we have two non-parallel (why?) lines both contained in a plane. Thus, they intersect.